# Re-signing app during install vsto

Tags: outlook, vsto

I have created a fairly simple Outlook AddIn and during the install I need the users to enter a couple of configuration settings. The problem I have is when it comes to the install I get an error saying that the computed hash in the manifest doesn't match (basically because I have changed some of the settings from when the dll was first built).

My question is how can I either re-sign this or get around it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're embedding Application Configuration settings somewhere that they shouldn't be.

The solution is to move these configuration settings to an external configuration file and load your settings dynamically at runtime. An external configuration file will not form part of the signed assembly and therefore won't ruin your signed distribution.

It is worth noting that the .NET *System.Configuration* classes **do not work very well with assemblies** and especially badly for VSTO assemblies (see multiple problems reported here on SO: [594298](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594298/c-dll-config-file)). As such I would recommend that you would either roll your own configuration class or read up heavily on the [ConfigurationManager.OpenMapperExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration.aspx) method to override the configuration file being targeted.

Additionally If you're currently using ClickOnce then this project sounds like it would be better suited to deployment via a [Windows Installer Package](http://www.codersource.net/csharp_installer_projects.html).

Comment: The add-in connects to a web service but the address of that web service is entered on install (changes per client) so this needs to be in the app config, the username and password I can easily move to the registry so they aren't the problem it's the web service address that is.

Comment: Gazeth - How are you installing? I'm not suggesting you move them to the Registry, you can move them all to a config file but they can't be in the Assembly. Where are your config settings written to / read from at the moment?

Comment: I tend to do the above install with the windows installer package and add a custom action to lay down a seprate config file to a know appdata path. You will have to roll you own class to read the file but that is no hard. you can then edit / intall the config file. as jamiei says id its just a single ws address may be the registry is the way to go .

Comment: I have moved my username and password to the registry just not sure how to get around the ws reference stuff in the app.config file and move that out of the assembly

Comment: I'm still confused as to your setup Gazeth. Move your config file to a separate file as per 76mel's and my own original suggestion and you will no longer have this problem.