# Access MySettings from other Project in Solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, .net-3.5, settings

Is it possible to access the [My.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611%28VS.80%29.aspx) of an other DLL referenced in the current Project? I have a Database project in which Settings the ConnectionString is stored. I need access to this Setting in an other Project(for Log-File).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have helped myself by a class in the Database-Project which has a function getAppSetting:

```
Public NotInheritable Class Helper
   Private Sub New()
   End Sub

   Public Shared Function getAppSetting(ByVal key As String) As String
       Dim returnValue As Object = My.Settings(key)
       If returnValue Is Nothing Then
           Return String.Empty
       Else
           Return returnValue.ToString
       End If
   End Function
End Class
```

I can call this function from my other project to get f.e. the ConnectionString.

Comment: Better is to past the setting to the other assembly. This removes the dependency between the two assemblies, and allow you to change  the database project's implementation, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at something like the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`, I know it works for web apps, not sure about database projects.

Then you could get your connection string with a command like:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Comment: My database-Project is a Class Library. The point is that i didnt know how to access its AppSettings from a different ddl. My workaround with a public function that returns it works. I think its not possible to access the AppSettings(My.Settings in .Net 2.0) from another dll(perhaps because of security concerns).

Comment: I have tried follwing without success: http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/accessappconfigfromdll.html
(section is nothing so i got a NullReferenceException)

Comment: Hi Tim, i think you should be able to expose your setting from the DLL with the settings in a similar way to your answer, but have you considered maybe just having your settings against your EXE instead?
This is a good reason why; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594298/c-dll-config-file/1009227#1009227