# How to save changes to app.config file from runtime for a Visual Studio Add-In

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-addins

Thanks to [Is there a config type file for Visual Studio Add-In?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925308/is-there-a-config-type-file-for-visual-studio-add-in)  I was able to create an app.config file for the Visual Studio add-in I am developing with the ability to read/write to it.

Now I am having trouble saving the changes made to it at runtime. I have been running the following test code, but when I look the app.config file after running in debug, nothing has changed.

```
Dim pluginAssemblyPath As String = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
Dim configuration As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(pluginAssemblyPath)
Dim test1 As String = configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Item("Key1").Value

configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Item("Key1").Value = "Is this thing on?"

Dim test3 As String = configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Item("Key1").Value
configuration.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = True
configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
```

Comment: Check this out http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/vbnet-read-write-appconfig (full disclosure - this is my article)

Comment: This was not helpful, but I had someone else help me out:
     ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")

Use that after the last line of what I have above. The actually app.config file will not change, but the config file inside of bin does.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim pluginAssemblyPath As String = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
   'Dim configuration As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(pluginAssemblyPath)
    Dim test1 As String = configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Item("Key1").Value

    configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Item("Key1").Value = "Is this thing on?"

    Dim test3 As String = configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Item("Key1").Value
    configuration.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = True
    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

The actual app.config will not change, but the config file inside of the bin folder does.