# Reading from app.config file when you don't have access to main .exe

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, app-config

We have created an add-in which runs correctly but unable to read from the associated app.config file. We believe the main culprit is that we are running as add-in and can't add the config values to main .exe.

I was wondering is there a way to read these values?

Comment: Add-in runs off its own app.config. Make sure it is named `myAddIn.exe.config`. But if you want to read from main application's app.config - you need to use config manager and load that app.config and read it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location

Comment: Yes, it's named as myAddin.exe.config and unable to read. I have verified that config file is available in the same directory.

Comment: I suspecting that your add-in is not EXE. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925308/is-there-a-config-type-file-for-visual-studio-add-in

Comment: That worked like a charm.