# Problems in reading DLL app.setting

Tags: c#, dll, app-config, application-settings

i have problems in reading DLL application setting in c# Visual Studio 2010.
I post a sample code of the get workarounded using reflection because with the ConfigurationManager fails.

```
private string LDAPDomain 
{  
    get
    {
        string strPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName;
        string val = GetValues(strPath, "LDAPDomain"); 
        return val;
    }
}


//strPath is path of the file.
//strKey is key to access

private string GetValues(string strPath, string strKey)
{
    System.Configuration.Configuration con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(strPath);
    string strValue = con.AppSettings.Settings[strKey].Value;

    return strValue;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting the main project referencing the DLL to pick up the app settings it doesn't work like that. The `ConfigurationManager` will read the config for the executing assembly, you need to put all the necessary configuration into your app if you want to use this.

Alternatively you can *manually* read the contents of your DLL's app.config file - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190539/equivalent-of-app-config-for-library-dll) for some example code.