# C# console application to dll file

Tags: c#, dll, console-application

I have c# code that initializes a force feedback joystick and plays force effect file. I want to change this c# console application into a dll file so that I can use it in labview.

[Converting a C# Console App to a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839498/converting-a-c-sharp-console-app-to-a-dll)

What I understood from this post is that I just need to create a class library and copy paste my codes there, is this correct? I did get a dll file by just doing that. If I'm wrong can you explain how to convert a console application to a dll?

Comment: Actually you can just change the output type in the properties for it to come out as a dll, but for readability it is better to make a new class and do the copy paste.

Answer (score 4):

Remember a DLL does not automatically execute the "Main" method. So:

1. Set the output type to **Class Library**
2. Compile
3. Add the DLL to your Labview project
4. Call **JoystickProjectMainClass.Main()** in your Labview project (I can't help you with that, too long ago ;) ) and it should run.