# How do I use the DLL App.Config Hack for Mail Host Settings

Tags: .net, xml, dll, sendmail, configuration-files

This was from this question but I was told to ask a new one > [[Equivalent to 'app.config' for a library (DLL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190539/equivalent-of-app-config-for-library-dll/25123487#25123487][1])

Basically I am converting a console app to a DLL and I want to use config settings.
They are saying to use an XML file (although I cannot get it to work - all strings come back as blank) but despite that I want to know how to replicate things like Mail Settings.

So how would I go about replicating thing like mail settings e.g

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp>
      <network host="generic.smtp.local"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

In an XML file that is just values not actually config for anything. Do I just need to pass these mail settings in manually to each call of a SendEmail method or can they be reproduced in a similar way as it would be good to keep all settings in one config file.

Thanks