# How to make C# project to use its own config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, app-config

Let's say I have 2 projects in C#:

- A class library project called **Repository** that encapsulates the database-access logic (implements CRUD methods to be consumed by any client). This project has an `App.config` file that defines a key called `Username`, with value `user01`.
- An ASP.NET (for example, an MVC application) project called **Website** that uses the Repository project as a reference, and it consumes the methods provided by Repository. This project has a `Web.config` file that defines a key called `Username`, with value `manager01`.

The problem I've found out is that, when any Repository method retrieves the value of the Username key, it will not retrieve the value `user01`. If called from website, it'll retrieve the value `manager01`; if called from another project that does not have a key called `Username` in its own config file, it'll throw a `NullReferenceException`.

My queston is: how can I force the Repository project (or any project, for that matter) to use its **own** config's keys instead of the caller's config keys?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190539/equivalent-to-app-config-for-a-library-dll

Comment: I added an answer in the duplicate question if you don't find a suitable answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/42026907/1351076](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42026907/1351076)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include another .config file into the main project config file.

Obviously if you set like startup project a website, your application will read his .config file  before.

Into that file use this for include another config file to read

```
<securityConfiguration configSource="AnotherConfigurationFile.config" />
```

PS: put the others config file all in the same folder.