# C# dll config in deployement

Tags: c#

I've got an exe that references a dll file.  The DLL file has a configuration  mydll.dll.config
The properties are accessed through

```
Properties.Settings.Default.mysetting;
```

The issue is that when deployed, I don't know where the settings are that the DLL is using. The config file is deployed in the same location as the exe and the dll file.  To make a change to the dll, I had to recompile and deploy it.  For my knowlege, where are the settings referenced?  Are they actually compiled into the dll?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190539/equivalent-to-app-config-for-a-library-dll

Comment: I'm not sure but sharing with you my experience, I believe your main config file will be used for that like `app.config` changes to `myapp_name.exe.config` where from you can read the settings. It also looks like you are using resource file, for that you may need to copy resource file on the same path, MS Docs could be helpful like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2022)

Comment: So If I use Properties.Settings.Default then those are compiled in?  I tried adding to the exe config file, but kept getting an error from the config file. Unrecognized section