# Reading specific config file

Tags: c#, app-config

I made my custom configuration classes to parse data from my config section.
My project is class library which means it creates dll. I found this way to retrieve my config section:

```
return (ReportServerConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionGroup + "/" + sectionName);
```

But this only works for .exe applications.
I waned to test my dll with specific config in some integration test but I cannot manage to read from correct config.

How to read from app.dll.config file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Dll config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594298/c-dll-config-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ConfigurationManager's OpenExeConfiguration(string) method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx