# Providing Settings for a DLL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dll, settings

All, firstly I am aware of this very useful question and related answers  [C# DLL config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594298/c-sharp-dll-config-file). However, I need some advice on the best way to proceed in my specific case.

I have a large application that uses embedded SQL. To make the burden of writing SQL easier I have developed an SQL Editor facility with a built in snippet library and other such niceties, alleviating users of the burden of launching Management Studio each time they want to test a query and providing a library of common commands. This utility is a good tool I may want to embed in other apps so I have made it a DLL. Now what are my options for storing the setting for this application?

1. Creating the settings using a .config file in the main application and pass a properties object to the DLL; which is saved by the main app on DLL closure. In this case (probably my best option) is there a pattern I can use to handle changes to my editors settings?.
2. Create a .config for the DLL and store the settings in the same place regardless of the calling app. [note, I have seen the problems with doing this in the linked question - I am only likely to ever have the DLL called from a single app].
3. Any other magical ways?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Personally, I would guess that it doesn't matter what kind of app or DLL you have. Simply save the settings somewhere in an XML file in e.g. "%APPDATA%\YourApp\configuration.xml".

Comment: "alleviating users of the burden of launching Management Studio" ???  Sounds like you're writing a new SSMS.  I'd be interested to hear more about this.

Comment: Well, it is a trimmed down version of SSMS. It will facilitate direct testing and ability to add authoured SQL directly into the maiin app after testing. It has a SQL parser to test syntax, a full find replace facility and an SQL snippet library (like that in LINQPad). I have used the book "Dissecting a C# Application" to build a slim editor based upon [ICSharpCode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor). I have rewritten the majority of this to make it look like VS2012. It looks great but is not finished...