# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXX"] is returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a console application in which website project is added as dll. Inside dll `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXX"]` is called which is always returning `null`.

But web.config in dll has connectionstring named 'XXX'. Can any one suggest what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have anything within the <connectionstrings> tag? i guess you have added the connection string but in some other tag. see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: yes my web.config file has <connectionstirngs> tag below I added my code  <connectionStrings>
        <clear/>
        <add name="XXX" connectionString="server=XX;database=test;uid=ai;pwd=ui123;" />
     </connectionStrings>

Comment: add this in your console application config

Comment: @EhsanUllah I added above code to config file now its working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think .config file of the .dll is added to your console project together with the dll. You need to have the .config in your executing project.

Comment: .config should be in .dll this .dll we will include in many console apllications.

Comment: @Lydia There is not an easy solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1009227/1094268

Answer (score 2):

Try copying the config file to your console project. Or at least the connection strings section. Probably in an App.config.

Comment: Yeah usually it's done via post-build processing - copying all the needed cfg-files

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly different problem that I haven't seen an answer to. I was using.

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXXX"].ConnectionString;

When I opened up web.config I saw that the connection string I had created was prefixed with "WebApplicationAPI.Properties.Settings." - putting the entire string in worked for me:

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebApplicationAPI.Properties.Settings.XXXX"].ConnectionString;

Answer (score 0):

Your config file is not in the .dll. So you're referencing nothing I would suspect! Unless you've manually copied the web.config file to the correct location or references it via an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

web.config is for web application.

For console application you have to use app.config.

Well, actually that's the default configuration for C#, I won't be surprised some advanced user could make it go the other way arround.