# Defining Connection String in Console Application

Tags: c#

I am trying to `create a connection` but, it is always taking `null`.
Below I am mentioning a way, how i am doing it :

Program.cs :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CreateConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

App.config :

```
<configuration>

   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CreateConnection" connectionString="data source=MyDatabase;initial catalog=TestDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;user id=ABC;password=Admin@123;App=EntityFramework;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: please post more of the App.Config code

Comment: do you have `<connectionStrings> </connectionStrings>` around the the row in app config?

Comment: Yes... Let me post more

Comment: have you added a reference to System.Configuration DLL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings\["XXX"\] is returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565275/configurationmanager-connectionstringsxxx-is-returning-null)

Comment: Can you post some more code of program.cs?

Comment: Yes I have added reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used following way. Check if this helps Used for MySQL

In App.config file

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="DBConnectionString" 
   value="server=localhost;userid=root;database=databasename"/>
  </appSettings>
```

In Program.cs

```
public static string m_strMySQLConnectionString;
static MySqlConnection m_mySqlConnection;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  m_strMySQLConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnectionString"].ToString();
  m_mySqlConnection = null;
 }
```

In DB Helper Function

```
public string GetValueFromDB(string strQuery)
    {
        string strData = "";

        try
        {
            if (m_mySqlConnection == null)
                OpenDatabase();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strQuery) == true)
                return string.Empty;

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, m_mySqlConnection);
            object objValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (objValue == null)
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                strData = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }

            if (strData == null)
                return string.Empty;
            else
                return strData;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
            return string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
            return string.Empty;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseDatabase();
        }
    }
```