# How to enable Entity Framework with mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have a Windows form project with C#. I am trying to enable Entity Framework with a mysql database. But I am not finding any instruction available. Is it something that is not possible?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159338/defining-connection-string-in-console-application/45159733#45159733

Answer (score 1):

Here are some step-by-step walkthroughs for using EF with MySQL

EF Core 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html

EF 6 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html#connector-net-ef6-example