# What shall I do with projectname.dll.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a .NET web application and the configuration is in `web.config` which lives in the root of my project (obviously).

Recently I've noticed that `<projectname>.dll.config` is also created during the build and it's basically a copy of my `web.config` file. The site works just fine without this file and I wondering whether I need it?

I must say that my solution consists of a few projects and the `.dll.config` is created for the main (web) project only.

Are there any guidelines on how to organise the configuration settings? Shall I disable creation of this file if it is possible? If it is possible how can I do it? Or shall I just ignore it?

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594298/c-sharp-dll-config-file

Answer (score 0):

Its not going to harm you, so you can leave as is and not bother at all. But if you want it to be gone follow below steps:-

Add a reference to System.Configuration

Add a new Application Configuration File and the name it [Your project].dll.config

Change the BuildAction property of the config file to Content

Change the Copy to Output property to "Copy Always"