# Access app.config from DLL

Tags: c#, app-config

I´ve read [this post from Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/594306/2528063) showing how to read an `app.config`-file from a DLL. When I try to read the `userSettings` from within that library I get an empty list:

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("CodeGeneratorApp.exe").AppSettings.Settings;
```

The `app.config`-file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="CodeGenerator.CodeGeneratorApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <CodeGenerator.CodeGeneratorApp.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="CodeExtensions" serializeAs="Xml">
            <value>
              <CodeExtensionList>
                <Extension AssemblyQualifiedName="CodeGenerator.Extensions.NamespaceTypesExtension, CodeGenerator, Culture=neutral">
                  <NamespaceTypesExtension />
                </Extension>
                ...
              </CodeExtensionList>
            </value>
          </setting>
        </CodeGenerator.CodeGeneratorApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

My DLL and the application are located in the same folder and even when I add

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("CodeGeneratorApp.exe").AppSettings.Settings;
```

to a QuickWatch I see that the `FilePath` of the returned object is set to the applications config-file, so it was found and opened properly.

In particular what I´m trying to achieve is to de-serialize the `value` for `CodeExtensionList` but I don´t know how to even access that section within the file.

Comment: Is it because those are `userSettings` and you're asking for `AppSettings`?

Comment: I don't think you can get to user-scope settings this way.  I think you need [this ugly animal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269(v=vs.110).aspx).  There is a lot to dislike about System.Configuration, "don't do this" is the only good advice I can think of.  An EXE project ought to configure the class library it uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working with the help of klashar. As the information is located within the `userSettings` we need to query this particular section of course. This can be done by the following code:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("CodeGeneratorApp.exe");
var sectionGroup = (ClientSettingsSection) config.GetSection("userSettings/CodeGenerator.CodeGeneratorApp.Properties.Settings");
```

Now we can get the `SettingElement` within that group, in my case there´s only one so we can take the very first, query its content as Xml, write that Xml to a `MemoryStream` and de-serialize that stream:

```
var setting = (SettingElement) sectionGroup.Settings[0];

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CodeExtensionList));
MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream(); 
StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(stm);
stw.Write(setting.Value.ValueXml.InnerXml);
stw.Flush();
stm.Position = 0;
var value = ser.Deserialize(stm) as CodeExtensionList;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have got you have asked for.
There is not [appSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(v=vs.71).aspx) section in your app.config. That is why `AppSettings.Settings` returns an empty list.

*Edit*

It seems you are trying to load custom section `CodeGenerator.CodeGeneratorApp.Properties.Settings`. If that is the case, the following code should do the work:

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager
    .OpenExeConfiguration("CodeGeneratorApp.exe")
    .GetSection("userSettings/CodeGenerator.CodeGeneratorApp.Properties.Settings")
```