# App.Config of managed DLL when referenced by an un-managed EXE

Tags: c#, c++, app-config

I have a managed DLL (MyAssembly.dll) written in C#. I am storing configuration settings in the Properties.Settings list that is serialized by Visual Studio to the app.config.

All nice and dandy.

I have an unmanaged application written in Visual C++. It references the our managed DLL. It works fine, but **no MyAssembly.dll.config file is deployed** by the build process to folder of the unmanaged executable. How can I change my configs after deployment?

Comment: It doesn't work either if your main program is written in C#.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594298/c-sharp-dll-config-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `app.config` is a C# concept and it is not available in C++ artifacts, unless you are writing in MC++ (Managed C++).

Native C++ applications have no infrastructure support for handling such files. For this reason you have to do it by hand.