# How can I load a dll-config using ConfigurationManager?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have two projects in a solution; one is a dll-project and the other is a web API. Both .NET Core.

When I test the dll, or compile it and run as a console app the configuration works just fine. When I reference it from the web API, everything builds and the resulting .dll.config is placed in the correct place. Looking at `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase` gives me the expected path.

However, when I run the web API in debug and hit a breakpoint in the referenced project, none of the expected settings are found in  ConfigurationManager.Appsettings.

Is there something I have overlooked, or do I need to specify the configfile for ConfigurationManager when using it as a DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you retrieve a Configuration object using the "normal" method, the object you get back is tied to the configuration of the App Domain you are executing in, rather than the particular assembly.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1009227/9212040) for more detailed information.

But in short, `ConfigurationManager.Appsettings` always read config file of main application, but still you can read dll configs this way:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("foo.dll");
```